# Unity project does not build to iOS:Internal build system error. BuildProgram exited with code 8. Player Build Failed

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

**Summary**:
AR Project using Lightship ARDK does not build to iOS despite every GameObject is disabled.

System: Mac OS Ventura 13.0.1, MacBook Air M1, 16gb RAM.

1. What is the error?
2. Exact Error Messages
3. Project overview & past tries to resolve the issue

**What is the error?**

Unity Project runs in Editor but does not build to iOS

**Exact error messages:**

[image]

Expanded Error 1

```html
Internal build system error. BuildProgram exited with code 8.
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at iOSPlayerBuildProgram.SetupTargetForInludedFile(IncludedFile file)
   at iOSPlayerBuildProgram.AddProjectFile(NPath srcPath, NPath dstPath, Boolean addToEmbeddedBinaries, String targetGUID, Boolean shouldAddToProject, SymlinkType symlinkType)
   at iOSPlayerBuildProgram.SetupCopyPlugin(NPath pluginPath, NPath pluginDest, Plugin plugin)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at PlayerBuildProgramLibrary.PlayerBuildProgramBase.SetupCopyPlugins() in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/IncrementalBuildPipeline/PlayerBuildProgramLibrary/PlayerBuildProgramBase.cs:line 537
   at PlayerBuildProgramLibrary.PlayerBuildProgramBase.SetupPlayerBuild() in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/IncrementalBuildPipeline/PlayerBuildProgramLibrary/PlayerBuildProgramBase.cs:line 174
   at iOSPlayerBuildProgram.SetupPlayerBuild()
   at PlayerBuildProgramLibrary.PlayerBuildProgramBase.RunBuildProgram() in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/IncrementalBuildPipeline/PlayerBuildProgramLibrary/PlayerBuildProgramBase.cs:line 168
   at PlayerBuildProgramTypeWrapper.Run(String[] args)
   at Program.Main(String[] args)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

Expanded Error 2

```html
BuildFailedException: Incremental Player build failed!
UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/Modules/BeeBuildPostprocessor.cs:663)
UnityEditor.iOS.iOSBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/Common/iOSBuildPostprocessor.cs:508)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.iOS.iOSBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/Common/iOSBuildPostprocessor.cs:515)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/Modules/DefaultBuildPostprocessor.cs:28)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:370)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

Expanded Error 3

```html
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 3 seconds (2915 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

Expanded Error 4:

```html
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ce] in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:193 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:94 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

**Project Overview, tries to resolve**
[image]

The project is an AR App that allows you to control a butterfly, by placing cube. He will fly to one cube after another. I am using the Niantic ARDK.

Tries to resolve the issue:

Deactive all Game Objects except the camera, build to iOS -> Does not work

Deactivate all Game Objects (Empty Scene), build to iOS -> not working.

Create a new Unity Project using a empty 3D scene, build to iOS -> Works

Create a new Unity Project using ARDK, build to iOS -> Works

One more thought: I am using iCloud Drive, maybe it uploaded something and deleted the local copy?

Hope someone can help :) Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the code isn't failing when it starts to run?  Index was outside the bounds of the array is a runtime error not a build error.  I suspect you are getting an event before the constructor is completed.  Usually adding a test for null in event handler prevents startup errors.

Comment: So the game runs normally in editor. 

The issue appears shortly after a pop up windows that says " No Adaptive Performance found" , you can Ignore it or go to settings. Usually ignoring it worked.

Comment: That is not what your errors said.  See : https://forum.unity.com/threads/adaptive-performance-no-active-loader-was-found.1048058/